# Converting one to many relation into a json column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to query two information_schema tables in PostgreSQL - tables and columns in order to get the following result:

table_name - columns_as_json_array

Sort of converting this one to many relation into a json array column.
I tried a lot of different methods and came up with somethings like this:

```
SELECT t.table_name, c.json_columns
FROM information_schema.TABLES t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
  SELECT table_name, json_agg(row_to_json(tbc)) AS json_columns
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS tbc
  WHERE t.table_name = tbc.table_name
  GROUP  BY table_name
  ) as c ON TRUE;
```

This results a list of table_names but the json_columns always contains all of the columns available instead of the columns of that certain table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see the point for a lateral join here. As far as concerns, you can get the expected results by aggregating `information_schema.columns`:

```
select table_name, json_agg(row_to_json(c)) json_columns
from information_schema.columns c
group by table_name
order by table_name
```